# CouchDB with Android application

Tags: java, android, gwt, couchdb

We have a web application developed iin GWT using couchDb as database, now we want to develop android application for the same web application. So we want to use same coucDB database for the android application also, in order to keep the one database for both applications (web & android).

So how to configure android application with couchDB.

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

If your app does not need to work offline, you can just use your favorite HTTP client library, or a CouchDB-specific Java library to access your database over the network.

If you want to have your app maintain its own copy of your database (for offline and/or peer-to-peer usage), check out [Couchbase Lite for Android](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android) — it can replicate with Apache CouchDB (which it sounds like you're using) or with Couchbase Sync Gateway (which has a few extra permissions management features).

You can also do similar from JS, if you're making a PhoneGap/Cordova app instead of native Java, by using the [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) library instead of the native Couchbase Lite library.

Comment: [Cloudant Sync](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android) is also an option if you want to use native Android Java code.